# Does DB2 for z/OS have isolation level similar to READ ONLY in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, db2, isolation-level

Does DB2 for z/OS have isolation level similar to READ ONLY in Oracle?
I need to implement several big selects to DB2 and also I need to retrieve consistent data which was commited on time when queries were started, so I need something like 'snapshot isolation level'. As far as I know in Oracle it can be implemented by READ ONLY isolation level, but what about DB2 for z/OS?

Comment: Google for 'isolation levels in db2 mainframe with examples'. [First hit](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=isolation+levels+in+db2+mainframe+with+examples)  [Second hit](http://www.dbatodba.com/db2/how-to-do/what-are-the-db2-isolation-levels)  [Third hit](http://www.mainframegurukul.com/ibmmainframeforums/Various-Locking-mechanism-for-cursors-and-other-SQL-post2425.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but all this links don't contain an answer on my question.

Comment: By default Oracle queries have a transaction isolation level of READ CONSISTENT, ie. as-of the start of the query. If you need consistency as-of the start of the transaction then you use SERIALIZABLE. READ ONLY is the same isolation level as READ CONSISTENT, but prevent writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 for z/OS does not have "read only" isolation level (nor does Oracle, as "read only" is a transaction state, not an isolation level).

You can avoid lock waits by queries if you use the [*currently committed* concurrent access resolution option](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.perf/src/tpc/db2z_accesscommitteddata.dita?lang=en), however, note that it does not implement "snapshot isolation" per se -- a query that uses this option will see the latest committed changes, even if those changes were committed *after* the query started.

Comment: The Oracle docs disagree, and do document read-only as an isolation level. http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#BABGEGBC

Comment: @DavidAldridge -- I'm not surprised, Oracle docs also disagree with each other: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10005.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is a `FOR READ ONLY` clause in DB2 z/OS. You add it at the end of your query.

> For tables in which updates and deletes are allowed, specifying FOR
>   READ ONLY can possibly improve the performance of FETCH operations as
>   DB2® can do blocking and avoid exclusive locks. For example, in
>   programs that contain dynamic SQL statements without the FOR READ ONLY
>   or ORDER BY clause, DB2 might open cursors as if the UPDATE clause was
>   specified.

Here is the [Info Center article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_readonlyclause.dita?lang=en) with more information.

---

If you're really looking for the DB2 version of "Serializable", then you are looking for [Repeatable Read](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.perf/src/tpc/db2z_isorr.dita?lang=en).